# Better way to get second level foreign key data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am using the following templatetag but I feel like there has got to be a better way.  I am trying to get a list of skills that a provider has while cycling through all providers.  Eventually, I plan to a filter for which providers to use.

```
#skills.py

from django import template
from ..models import ProviderProfile, Skill

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('util/li.html')
def get_skills(user):
    provider = ProviderProfile.objects.get(user=user)
    skills = provider.skills.all()
    print(f"skills are {skills}")
    skills_list = skills.values_list("skill_id", flat=True)
    skill_list = Skill.objects.filter(id__in = skills_list)
    context = {'list': skill_list,}
    return context
```

and the models are

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False, null=True,)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

class ProviderProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, 
        primary_key=True,
    )
    pitch = models.TextField(blank=True)
    radius = models.SmallIntegerField(default=30, blank=True, null=True, help_text='Work radius in miles')
    notes = GenericRelation(Note)
       
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}"

class ProviderSkill(models.Model):
    provider = models.ForeignKey(ProviderProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="skills")
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="std_skills")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["provider", "skill"]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.provider} - {self.skill}"
```

with the following view

```
@login_required
def clientProviderListView(request):
    providers = ProviderProfile.objects.all()

    context = {'providers': providers,}
    return render(request,'accounts/client_provider_list.html', context)
```

and the main template

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Providers{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2 class="me-1">Providers</h2>
{% if providers %}
<div id="client_p" class="d-flex">
    <div class="row row-cols-1">
        {% for provider in providers %}
        <div class="col text-center p-2">
            {% include 'accounts/partials/provider_card.html' %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% else %}
<div class="container-fluid my-2">
    <button class="btn btn-warning">There are not providers in the system</buttton>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Could someone point me in a better directions?

This is what I tried and it works but I think it is clunky

Comment: Likely it is better to do the querying in the view, so not in a template tag, otherwise, you make queries *per* `Provider`, and thus introducing the *N+1 problem*.

Comment: But how do I filter our just the given providers data in the template?

Comment: Exactly *what* providers do you want. What is the criterium to filter in/out?

Comment: I am displaying each provider with profile details and the skills they have.

Comment: but you say "*But how do I filter our just the given providers data in the template?*". So filter out *what*?

Comment: Filter the skills for a provider since it is not part of the provider profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely it is better to do the querying in the view, so not in a template tag, otherwise, you make queries *per* `Provider`, and thus introducing the *N+1 problem*.

First of all, we can improve the modeling, your `ProviderSkill` is essentially the junction table of a many-to-many relation between `ProviderProfile` and `Skill`, therefore `related_name='skills' makes not much sense since it does not return` Skill`s`, but `ProviderSkill` objects. We can improve the modeling with:

```
class ProviderProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    pitch = models.TextField(blank=True)
    radius = models.SmallIntegerField(
        default=30, blank=True, null=True, help_text='Work radius in miles'
    )
    notes = GenericRelation(Note)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(
        Skill, through='ProviderSkill', related_name='providers'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user}'


class ProviderSkill(models.Model):
    # no related_name='skills'
    provider = models.ForeignKey(ProviderProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['provider', 'skill']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.provider} - {self.skill}'
```

We can effectively fetch all the skills for all `ProviderProfile`s with:

Now in the view we can prefetch the `skills`:

```
@login_required
def clientProviderListView(request):
    providers = ProviderProfile.objects.select_related('user').prefetch_related(
        'skills'
    )
    return render(
        request,
        'accounts/client_provider_list.html',
        {
            'providers': providers,
        },
    )
```

and in the template we can enumerate over the skills with:

```
{% for provider in providers %}
    {{ povider }}
    <b>skills</b>:
    <ul>
    {% for skill in provider.skills.all %}
        <li>{{ skill }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am fairly new to django and still don't know all the ins and outs